# Is it possible to retrieve job metadata from BigQuery API (without querying)

Tags: google-bigquery

'm currently working on a project that needs to look at job metadata without actually querying using the bigQuery console. is it possible to access metadata from INFORMATION_SCHEMA using client libraries such as Python and without having to query? thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you would use the [get_job method](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.html#google.cloud.bigquery.client.Client.get_job) to return a job instance.  It returns a job instance that looks like this:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/Job

The same applies for get_dataset, and get_table if you needed to get meta data about those objects.